# How to append html element inside a function

Tags: javascript, html, escaping, decode

This is the code I have from a function:

```
.text(function (d, i) { return data[i].label + " <tspan style='font-weight:700;'>(" + data[i].value + ")</tspan>" });
```

but it `output` `MARCO &lt;tspan style='font-weight:700;'&gt;(7)&lt;/tspan&gt;` and not `MARCO <tspan style='font-weight:700;'>(7)</tspan>`.

So it is not evalutate as HTML. Where do I should decode the text before "inject" it?

Comment: From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/text/): *"We need to be aware that this method escapes the string provided as necessary so that it will render correctly in HTML. To do so, it calls the DOM method .createTextNode(), does not interpret the string as HTML."* . Always read the documentation before using an unfamiliar method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `html()` instead of `text()`. `text()` will encode the string and add it in DOM.

```
.html(function (d, i) {
    return data[i].label + " <tspan style='font-weight:700;'>(" + data[i].value + ")</tspan>"
});
```